# Xcode 4.4.1, iOS 5.1.1: Xcode cannot run using the selected device

Tags: ios, xcode

Need to to test my app on iphone 4 IOS 5.1.1. The provisioning profiles are ok. I get

"Cannot run using the selected device. No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version or..."

Of course I tried to set a lower deployment target but I still get the error. 
Any Ideas?

Comment: What deploymenttraget do you have? Or probably the iOS Version of your iPhone is too low. Just for your information: i had this problem recently (a few minutes ago) but with a wrong architecture (XCode 4.5). What i did is to delete armv7s (which has been added vom XCode automatically). Hope it helps